# Trying to add an object key to button. "Cannot read undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm creating this code to create a quiz.

The undefined error shows up when I'm trying to setData to give my buttons key strings. I'm doing so to try use that to check whether the answer buttons get assigned certain classes "correct" or "incorrect".

These buttons aren't fully fleshed out yet. Because I'm stuck on this one part. 
But, I get an undefined error in the selectAnswer function loop. I'm stuck and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers would be nice.

```
// This document, when the start button is clicked, shows questions, & starts the timer
var startButton = document.getElementById("start-btn");
var questionContainerEl = document.getElementById("question-container");
var startScreen = document.getElementById("start-screen");
var questionTitle = document.getElementById("question");
var choiceButtons = document.getElementById("choice-buttons");
//var buttonVal = 0;
var score = 0;
var shuffleQuestions, currentQindex;
var i = 0;

//Object Container to hold questions and answers
const questions = [{
    question: "What is 2 + 2?",
    answers: [
        {text: "4", correct: "true"},
        {text: "2", correct: "false"},
        {text: "3", correct: "false"},
        {text: "5", correct: "false"}
        ]
},
{
    question: "What is 4*4?",
    answers: [{text: '8', correct: "false"},
        {text: '16',correct: "false"},
        {text: '2', correct: "false"},
        {text: '6', correct: "false"},
        ]
},
{
    question: "Solve for x. y = 3x - 6",
    answers: [{text: '6', correct: "false"},
    {text: '3', correct: "false"},
    {text: '2', correct: "false"},
    {text: "idk", correct: "false"}]
}]; 

startButton.addEventListener('click',startGame);
//Start game function shows Question Cont. Shuffles Questions on an Arr.
function startGame() {
    startScreen.classList.add('hide');
    shuffleQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
    currentQindex = 0;
    questionContainerEl.classList.remove('hide');
    setNextQuestion();
}  
//Erases question and finds next one on Arr.
function setNextQuestion() {
    resetState();
    showQuestion(shuffleQuestions[currentQindex])
}
//Shows question as well as answers.
function showQuestion(questions) {
    questionTitle.innerText = questions.question;
    console.log(questionTitle);
    var ansLength = Object.keys(questions.answers).length;
    var ans;
    for(i = 0; i < ansLength; i++) {
        //When the answer button is selected questions goes to next object element
        ans = questions.answers[i];
        console.log(ans);
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = ans.text;
        button.classList.add('btn');

        if(ans.correct === "true") {
            button.correct = ans.correct;
            console.log("button:" + button.correct);

        } 
        button.addEventListener("click", selectAnswer);
        choiceButtons.appendChild(button);
    }
}
//removes buttons from choices.
function resetState() {
    while(choiceButtons.firstChild) {
        choiceButtons.removeChild(choiceButtons.firstChild)
    }
}
function selectAnswer(e) {
    var selectedButton = e.target;
    var isCorrect = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
    setStatusClass(document.body, isCorrect);
    var ar = Array.from(choiceButtons.children)
    for (buttons in ar) {
        setStatusClass(buttons, buttons.dataset.isCorrect);
    }
}
function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
    clearStatusClass(element);
    if (correct) {
        element.classList.add("correct");
    } else {
        element.classList.add("incorrect");
    }
}
function clearStatusClass(element){
    element.classList.remove("correct");
    element.classList.remove("incorrect");
}'''
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1772368

Comment: `for (buttons in ar)` -> `for (buttons of ar) {`

Comment: Thank you @HaoWu

Comment: This makes the code work. But, sets the class of each of the buttons to either correct or incorrect. @HaoWu